# Python: unknown # of files as function arg

Tags: python

Having this working code to read 2 files and reprint them:

```
import sys
args = sys.argv[1:]

def funcprint(arg1, arg1):
    with open(arg1, "r") as inp:
        for line in inp:
            print(line)
    with open(arg2, "r") as inp:
        for line in inp:
            print(line)

funcprint("C:/file1.txt", "C:/file2.txt")
```

But how would one pass an arbitrary number of files to the function? Having `*arg` instead of `1` & `2` results in `TypeError: invalid file:`, even with just 1 passed file.

As a side question, is there a way to shorten the function call if all files are in the same folder? Something like `funcprint("C:/": "file1.txt", "file2.txt")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass an arbitrary number of file names, you'd do:

```
def funcprint(*args):
    for f in args:
        with open(f, 'r') as inp:
            ...

funcprint("C:/file1.txt", "C:/file2.txt")
```

If the files are all in the same directory, you could do:

```
def funcprint(dir, *args):
    for f in args:
        with open('{}{}'.format(dir, f), 'r') as inp:
            ...

funcprint('C:/', 'file1.txt', 'file2.txt')
```

Comment: Ingeniously! Both of these solutions work like a charm 